# allocationSize and duplicated pk issue

Tags: oracle, ejb, jboss7.x

Jboss 7.2.0, ejb3, oracle
All entities in the project have defined sequence generator like
@SequenceGenerator(name="xx", sequenceName="yy" allocationSize="10")

For one-to-many relation sometimes I have issue with duplicated primary key. Not sure what is wrong here but after the transaction is rollback the sequence is reset and I've constraint violation errors all the time
I've changed allocationSize to 1 and it seems to be ok but what's reason ?

Comment: In an Oracle database a SEQUENCE is never reset by a rollback. Once numbers are taken from the SEQUENCE they're taken, and if a transaction is rolled back those numbers are lost. On the other hand, numbers derived from a SEQUENCE should never have meaning attached to them - they're just numbers. If JBoss is doing something to "reset" a sequence it's absolutely doing the wrong thing. Best of luck.

Comment: I think I found the reason because this time negative numbers were generated. And according to stackoverflow while creating oracle sequence parameter increment by has to be set to value 10 in my case

Answer (score 0):

see the discussion: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/104030?start=15&tstart=0

in your question is not clear the sequenceName is it a hibernate_sequence or oracle sequence? if it's oracle - you shouldn't have duplicates

```
@Id(generate = GeneratorType.SEQUENCE, generator = "mysequence")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "mysequence", sequenceName = "MY_SEQ",allocationSize=1)
//@SequenceGenerator(name = "mysequence", sequenceName = "hibernate_sequence")
@Column(name = "COVT_ID", primaryKey=true)
public long getId() {
return m_id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you used ddl-generation property with the value "drop-create-tables" property in your persistence.xml.  This cause all sequences and tables to be dropped and recreated with the initial values again and so, the same sequence values are reused.